# Can a Chwinga Grant a Given Person More Than one Charm?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, stacking

So, within the Chwinga statblock, which can be found in Tomb of Annihilation and Icewind Dale: Rime of the Icemaiden, this ability appears:

> Magical Gift (1/Day). The chwinga targets a humanoid it can see within 5 feet of it. The target gains a supernatural charm of the DM’s choice. See the Dungeon Master’s Guide for information on supernatural charms.

So, the question is how this interacts with the rule on simultaneous effects. Does Magical Gift linger along with the charm it bestows, or is it an instantaneous effect with the charm simply being bestowed, and thus able to be used an infinite amount of times on a given target without losing the effect of the blessings? (Yes, I am aware of the once per day limit, I'm asking if it could still be used every day to stack up effects, or possibly multiple Chwingas using it all at the same time for the same result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The relevant rules aren't defined well enough for this to have a canon answer

The crux here is whether Magic Gift has a lingering effect on the target or whether it is instantaneous and only creates the charm as a lingering effect. For spells duration would be defined, but for monster traits it isn't. Usually duration would be fairly clear, but in this case it isn't. It therefore comes down to the DM, and realistically how many charms they want to be handing out or are fine with the PCs hoarding. Notably charms have limited usage, so the expectation of them being expended rather than hoarded seems reasonable (including in world).

Comment: I think that it possibly could stack, because the names of the charms that are granted can be different, so the overlapping would be applied based on the charm granted, rather than the source of the charm.

Comment: @RevenantBacon That would be one of the outcomes/rulings.